# Как передать значение переменной JS в PHP SQL?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

есть ссылка, открывающая модальное окно

```
<a id="updatedetail" href="" data-id="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upDetail">Изменить</a>
```

есть JS-код, принимающий data-id в переменную

```
document.querySelectorAll('#updatedetail').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var showid = e.dataset.id;
  })
})
```

В модальном окне запускается вывод данных из БД на php

```
<?php 
  $detail_object = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `detail` WHERE `id`='значение переменной showid'");
  $detail = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($detail_object);
?>
```

Как передать значение переменной showid из JS в значение WHERE `id` = '...' ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно это реализовать с помощью объекта XMLHttpRequest, который позволит без перезагрузки страницы получить данные.
Пример:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#updatedetail').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var showid = e.dataset.id;
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = '<путь_к_вашему_файлу-обработчику>'; //где у вас делается запрос к БД
    const data = {id: showid}

    request.open("POST", url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    request.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            modal.innerHTML = request.responseText; //Здесь, собственно, выводим данные в модальное окно
        } else {
            console.log(response); //Здесь можно сделать обработку на случай ошибок
        }
    });
    request.send(data);
  });
});
```

P.S. и лучше, конечно же, модальное окно открывать тогда, когда данные в него уже были помещены, а не сразу по клику на ссылку.

То есть в теле условия

```
if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    modal.innerHTML = request.responseText; //Поместили данные
    modal.open(); //Открыли модальное окно
}
```

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понятно, как этот код применить к моей конструкции. Файла обработчика нет, весь код находится в одном PHP файле - подключение к БД, html-верстка и вставки php кода для отображения данных из БД. Внешнее только подключение JS кода. Что по итогу нужно указать в WHERE id = '...' ?

Comment: По итогу? Примерно вот это при условии использования кода из ответа: `$_POST['id']`. То есть получиться как-то так: `$detail_object = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `detail` WHERE `id`='" . $_POST['id'] . "');`

Comment: Я на самом деле не очень хорошо представляю решение без видимости полного кода, но с вашего позволения посоветую вот так применить ответ: `const url = '<путь_к_"код находится в одном PHP файле">; //где у вас делается запрос к БД`. А сам этот запрос на обновление обернуть в условие `if ($_POST["id"]) {//код запроса на обновление}`

Comment: Простите, но всё равно не понимаю :) весь код и не нужен, я всё описал выше: есть ссылка, запускающая модальное окно (код модального окна прописан в этом же файле). В модальном окне вставлен кусок php кода, где происходит вывод данных из БД. Какой код я могу вставить в конструкции <script></script> в том же файле, где прописан код ссылки и модального окна? и чему в моем случае равен const url (не оставлять же мне значение <путь_к_"код находится в одном PHP файле">)?

Comment: Немного изменил ответ: вы кликаете по ссылке, вызывая модальное окно, так? - Так! Оно у вас открылось, параллельно этому запустился процесс, который передаёт данные на сторону сервера. В комментарии выше этими данными на стороне сервера будет являться `$_POST["id"]`. А вместо `'<путь_к_"код находится в одном PHP файле">;` укажите путь к файлу, в котором у вас весь код (что это - index.php, detail.php?). То есть путь файла, в котором у вас прописан код модального окна

Comment: В теории принцип понял, всё сделал, как описали, но почему-то не работает. Не выводятся данные